# how can I connect to gitlab installed in ubuntu VM image?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, gitlab

I installed a gitlab in ubuntu VM image and external_url set as 192.168.71.12, when I input url http://127.0.0.1 in VM browser, it shows gitlab home page that can login.
But how can i connect to gitlab in local machine(PC), not only in VM?

These are the steps I took to install it

Download VMWARE Workstation 15 Player for windows

https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html

Download VMware of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Bionic Beaver (Final)

https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/

Setting Up VM image step (Chinese version)

https://blog.xuite.net/yh96301/blog/222632640-VMware+Player+6.0%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9DUbuntu+14.04%28%E4%B8%80%29

install GitLab in ubuntu VM(Chinese version)

https://blog.csdn.net/ayang1986/article/details/78881418

List out step in installation of GitLab

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y curl openssh-server ca-certificates

sudo apt-get install -y postfix

curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://192.168.71.12" apt-get install gitlab-ee

sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Then use firefox in ubuntu VM and input 127.0.0.1 can browse gitlab home page,

but when input 192.168.71.12, cannot connect to gitlab home page, input 192.168.71.12 in browser of local machine(PC) also cannot connect.

Comment: You may want to use the contact us link to request an account merger

Comment: thx for the merge

Answer (score 0):

The address 192.168.71.12 is in the subnet of the host computer? 
If not probably your VM are behind a nat and not bridged, that means you have to configure nat from host to VM for desired port, or change the network type of your VM to be reachable from the host computer

Comment: Sorry, I am weak in network knowledge. 192.168.71.12 is just type in external url.
did you means in network connection--> choose one of VMware Network Adapter VMnet1 / VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 
--> right click and choose properties --> in network feature tab, choose TCP/IPv4--> click content 
--> in general, use below ip address, type ip address as 192.168.71.12, 
subnet mask as 255.255.255.0, default gateway 192.168.71.0 --> click ok --> click ok.

Comment: and then edit virtual machine settings --> Network Adapter --> 
in Network connection, choose Custom:Specific virtual network as VMnet1/VMnet8, and open VM to test?

Comment: It did not work, could you specific how to change the network type?